# Why is the title "Yotsuba&!"?

Tags: yotsubato

The manga Yotsuba&! is a story about a little girl named Yotsuba. So, the title using her name makes sense, but why is there an additional '&' at the end?

[image]

This is the manga cover in English. It says Yotsuba&! and sometimes it's written Yotsubato! on some sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, *to* (と) is a Japanese particle that functions like English "and". If, for example, you wanted to say "Yotsuba & Tanaka", that would be *Yotsuba-to Tanaka* (よつばと田中).

So I suppose it makes sense that one might choose to write *Yotsuba-to!* as "Yotsuba&!".

---

As for *why* the title is "Yotsuba&!" / *Yotsubato* in the first place - I suppose it's related to the fact that all the chapter titles are of the form "Yotsuba & [something]", e.g. "Yotsuba & the Elephant" (#19) and "Yotsuba & Coffee" (#58).

Comment: but it still doesn't make sense, why the title is 'yotsuba and'?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Oh, I guess that's because all the chapter titles are of the form "Yotsuba and [something]".

Comment: it's so that the name hints at the genre. "Someone and…" has been heavily used in naming works of a similar genre over the years, and the consumers know what to expect from a work with such name